# Resource consumers in the Secret World

Tags: the-secret-world

In The Secret World, there are many abilities which 'consume' stacks of a resource, but the descriptive text for these abilities is a bit vague in what effects are gained by consuming the resource.

Using the example of Assault Rifles, there is an ability called "Three Round Burst".

This is the descriptive text:

> Consumes all Assault Rifle Resources. A single target Burst attack that hits 3 times, dealing 129 physical damage per hit.

As another example, here is the text from the "Shot of Anima" ability;

> Consumes all Assault Rifle Resources. A single target heal that heals for 139 and gives a 3.4% leech effect to the defensive target for 5 seconds.

There are many other abilities like this in game, in these particular instances, would these abilities do more damage or gain any other effect from consuming five stacks of Assault Rifle resource instead of say, one stack?

The reason I ask is there are other abilities in game which specifically state that the number of stacks consumed will have an effect, for example the "Fire at Will" ability;

> Consumes all Assault Rifle Resources. A TAoE Frenzy ability that deals 200 physical damage. An additional hit is performed for each Assault Rifle Resource consumed, dealing 63 physical damage per hit.

Is there a point in stacking the resource up to five before using the resource consuming ability in the instance where no benefit is mentioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information that I could find on the forums is that this tool tip does not specifically mention a use for the extra resources and so they will not have any additional affect.

However, this does not seem to be the case. After testing out some blade skills that I did have access to (And reducing my hud size so I could see the damage values again *sigh*) I can confirm that both Balanced Blade and Blade Dance are 'consume all resources' types of finishing moves (one AOE one single targeted/channeled). They both do noticeably more damage when used with five blade resources than with just a single blade resource.

With my QL-3 Blade my Balanced Blade with one resource did around 50-70 damage to those around me and critting for around 150 damage. When used with all five blade resources my base damage was 100-115 with my critical damage being around 300. Similarly, Blade Dance had the same differences with a base damage per strike matching Balanced Blade and showing the same increase when used with all five Blade Resources.

So I can not confirm this with every skill, I think other observances are likely accurate as mentioned with the ability "Fire At Will" where it will shoot an extra bullet for each resource.

Comment: I've heard the opposite - that they seem to have bigger effects the more resources you use.  (Otherwise, why build to 5?)  This isn't evident and I don't have a firm source handy, though.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem as well is I can find no 'From the devs' source on this. What I can say is most of the abilities that take All of the resources do seem to be from weapon choices that automagically generate their resources over time like Blades vs the ones that do have an impact or limited resource usage like Blood.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz doesn't *feel* like it with most AR attacks I've used in fairness, the differences in numbers that I've noticed could easily be explained by variance in damage range, unless of course its meant to be a subtle difference...

Answer (score 2):

Every consumer that have no beneficial effect of using more than x resources the amount of resources required to use that skill is stated in the description (and only uses the defined amount of resources) and every consumer that says "consumes all [weapon] resources" have beneficial effect (more damage) by using more than the minimal required resources.

But i did only tested this with Blood and Fist; other weapons may have a different behavior and there als still may be bugs in the skill description.